# Eliminating thin polygon connection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, geometry

I'm facing a problem concerning the fact that 2 polygons are connected by a thin connection.

[image: Polygon thin connection]

Is there an automatic method/process to deal with this situation, separating the 2 polygons and maintaining the same information for both?

I've already tried the "Correct Geometries" process.

I know that on QGIS 3.0 or later, there is the verify geometries toolbox, is there any specific configurations inside there that is able to deal with this?

Comment: How to identify, remove these "thin connections" and maintain the aspect of area and other info to both polygons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect but maybe good enough:

1. Buffer with a negative distance
2. Buffer results with the same distance but positive

[image]

And maybe clip the original polygon with the buffer

Answer (score 1):

Apply a negative buffer: Menu vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Buffer and set the buffer distance to a very small negative value - slightely bigger than the thickness of the connecting line.